# Is there any equivalent of an mix shader node but for displacement maps? If not how can I apply displacement only on a certain area of an object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, shaders

I am using the latest version of Blender
I do not want to use two different materials on the same object as it would just create a visible seam.
I want all of it to be it the same material.
I am asking this question because I want to put moss on an object but only on a certain place of it.

Comment: you can use a vertex group ;)

Comment: @Chris, did you mean Vertex Paint?

Answer (score 6):

Plug your 2 differents displacement maps (here *Noise Textures*) into a *MixRGB* and use a black and white mask image as a factor in the *MixRGB* in order to separate the 2 areas:

[image]

You can't use a *Mix Shader* for this purpose, *Mix Shader* is used to mix shaders, like *Diffuse, Emission, Principled BSDF, Glossy*, etc.